# How to make texture looks more realistic in blender paint tools?

Tags: textures, paint, blender

I'd like to make a character for my games, but I need tips how to make details. I tried burn tool, darken tool, lighten tools but it's going better. Also I don't know the details every brush function even I try it one by one.

on oldschool games like quake or half-life, they use fake shadow which is painted on texture or pattern to make details. I want to make something like that to make my character isn't looks like tiled. Did I need to use drawing pad?

[My characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvq6k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can define your general sense of art style for your games. Did you wanna make it realistic? or cartoony? or somewhere in the middle? this need a deep understanding of how materials work the way they do and the creation of it.

A big helpful tip i can give you to give you a running start is to study texture maps. Maps like albedo/diffuse, normal, roughness and what not to give you an understanding of what you're doing. I can see that you just starting out learning but don't give up and keep practicing!

Links:
https://conceptartempire.com/texture-maps/

youtube is a big help to study these things, an abundance of tutorial that can help you learn

Keep practicing!

Comment: ahhh thank you. yes I want to make something in middle, thanks alot for references